# Disabling clipboard ring in MSVC 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use ClipX on my computer to keep a clipboard history, and it works just fine.  After I upgraded to MSVC2012, however, it no longer picks up *any* of the copies I do inside Visual Studio.  It seems that Visual Studio is somehow catching the CTRL+C before ClipX is, or something?  Anyway, I prefer ClipX to MS's implementation, so I was hoping there was some way to just completely disable that functionality

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest version of ClipX available? Even though it's labeled "Beta", version 1.0.3.9 works well, and if you're on Win7 x64 there's a 64-bit version available, which is what I run. I'm not running Windows 8 or 8.1 yet so cannot comment on whether it works with those.

I'm running VS2013, and I cannot reproduce your problem exactly, but... I do have a similar problem (and solution):

I run VS as administrator (I change the properties of devenv.exe to always run as admin) for interop with IIS, among other reasons. ClipX still picks up the values from copies/cuts, but when I try to use the ClipX popup list to paste a value other than the current clipboard entry, it doesn't actually paste into Visual Studio. ClipX does move the item to the top of the list, and a second Ctrl+V does then paste the value into VS, but it's very annoying.

The solution is to run ClipX as administrator also. Since running a program as admin at startup/login is only possible through Task Scheduler, this is a bit of a pain to set up, but once I've set it up, ClipX has no problem interacting with VS (or any other program I run as admin).

If you are running VS as admin you could try running ClipX as admin (just right-click it in the Start menu) and see if it fixes your problem. If so, then worry about the Task Scheduler part. If it doesn't fix your problem, then well, it was worth a shot.